# How to bind several items to one key?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

For example, bind <kbd>Q</kbd> to both molotov/incendiary grenade and HE-grenade (in other words, toggle between molotov/incendiary grenade and HE-grenade with <kbd>Q</kbd>).
I know that [alias](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=314801693) has to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a toggle between two items (or settings) you can do it this way:

```
bind q usethis
alias usethis "use weapon_hegrenade; bind q usethat"
alias usethat "use weapon_molotov; use weapon_incgrenade; bind q usethis"
```

Whenever you press <kbd>Q</kbd> you'll change between HE and Molotov/Incendiary. If you switch to something else in between the script remembers the last item of those two you previously switched to. Also if you manage to hold both, Molotov and Incendiary, the script prefers the Incendiary over the Molotov.

Comment: You forgot the incendiary grenade.

Comment: edited the answer to support incendiary as well.

Comment: How do you hold both Molotov and Incendiary?

Comment: "if you manage to.." doesn't necessarily mean you are able to. Maybe in private games with mods, etc.

Comment: @dly: Why I sometimes have to press twice to switch item?

Comment: if you switched to one of these items manually the script doesn't know that and keeps following its order.

Comment: Doesn't work if "hold" for duck setting is enabled, "toggle" does. Doesn't apply to walk.