# How to bind several weapons to one key (toggle between weapons) in Quake?

Tags: quake

The options menu doesn't support rebinding weapons (beyond "next"/"previous", <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> keys by default), but console can be used for remapping, following the syntax:

```
bind <key> "impulse <#>"

1 - axe
2 - shotgun
3 - super shotgun
4 - nailgun
5 - super nailgun
6 - grenade launcher
7 - rocket launcher
8 - thunderbolt
```

For instance, `bind e "impulse 7"` to map the rocket launcher to the <kbd>E</kbd> key, and `bind MOUSE4 "impulse 3"` to bind the super shotgun to one of the mouse side buttons.

I assume that alias has to be used, as with [the Quake-derived Source engine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292453/how-to-bind-several-items-to-one-key). Personally I'd for example find having access to both shotguns with one key as convenient.

Comment: Apparently quotes `"` aren't mandatory in commands.

Comment: So what you want is to be able to have a single dedicated button to scroll through weapons in a specific category (e.g. using 'E' would scroll through the different shotguns)?

Comment: @Joachim Yes, one key to toggle between the specified weapons.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, this set of commands toggles between the two shotguns with the <kbd>Q</kbd> key:

```
alias select-shotgun "impulse 3; bind q select-super-shotgun"
alias select-super-shotgun "impulse 2; bind q select-shotgun"
bind q select-shotgun
```

`select-shotgun` and `select-super-shotgun` are arbitrary aliases — feel free to rename each to anything you desire, but avoid spaces and special characters (?). Input the lines one-by-one to the in-game console (may not be saved) or add to `autoexec.cfg` in your Quake folder.

You can use any other weapons by editing the `impulse <number>` part (see the question for syntax) and rebind by replacing the `q` keys in the example.

---

Should be compatible with the original game and more "vanilla-like" source ports such as Quakespasm and the reworked fork Quakespasm-Spiked.

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/quake/comments/cfb5hx/how_to_create_an_alias_in_quake_1/eub8ylj/?context=8&depth=9)